# Django prefetch_related cache not reflecting the changes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model **Banks**. and I have **six entities** in it.

This is my prefetch code.

```
queryset = Banks.objects.all().prefetch_related('field1','field2')
```

when I enter new entity into my Banks model and get the data, I still get only the old data. The newly added entity is not getting reflected when I download the data.

Comment: Please add more information on what you doing and how you do it. You "download" data? Also, did you actually call `bank_instance.save()` after you "enter new entiry"?

Comment: my data is stored into database, i can see that in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query. So, if you write the following:

```
>>> pizzas = Pizza.objects.prefetch_related('toppings')
>>> [list(pizza.toppings.filter(spicy=True)) for pizza in pizzas]
```

…then the fact that `pizza.toppings.all()` has been prefetched will not help you. The `prefetch_related('toppings')` implied `pizza.toppings.all()`, but `pizza.toppings.filter()` is a new and different query. The prefetched cache can’t help here; in fact it hurts performance, since you have done a database query that you haven’t used. So use this feature with caution!

Also, if you call the database-altering methods `add()`, `remove()`, `clear()` or `set()`, on related managers, any prefetched cache for the relation will be cleared.

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you be more specific how to clear cache.